# I'm having trouble with using hide/show and attach functions in c++

Tags: c++, hide, show

I am working on a c++ game and I have drawn two windows, but I can't figure out why my code isn't working when I'm trying to switch between the two windows. I have created two next buttons that should switch between the screens, but I am getting an unqualified id error for all of the show/hide functions and an error telling me that the attach function is inaccessible for the buttons I'm trying to attach. I'm sure it's a minor thing I'm overlooking, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include "Splash_screen.h"
#include "Instructions_screen.h"

using namespace Graph_lib;

//Screens

Splash_screen* home_win;
Instructions_screen* instruct_win;

//Buttons

Button* splash_button;
Button* instructions_button;

//Functions

void cb_splash_button();
void cb_instructions_button();



int main() {
    home_win = new Splash_screen{Point(100,100), 600, 500, "SSFB"};
    instruct_win = new Instructions_screen{Point(100,100), 600, 500, "SSFB"};

    Splash_screen.hide();

    splash_button = new Button{Point{250,400},100,50,"Next",Callback(cb_splash_button)};
    instructions_button = new Button{Point{540, 460}, 50, 30, "Next", Callback(cb_instructions_button)};

    home_win->attach(*splash_button);
    instruct_win->attach(*instructions_button);

    return gui_main();
}

void cb_splash_button() {
    Splash_screen.hide();
    Instructions_screen.show();
}

void cb_instructions_button() {
    Instructions_screen.hide();
    //CHANGE LATER
    Splash_screen.show();
}
```

Comment: It seems that `Splash_screen` and `Instructions_screen` are types, not objects. Have you tried `home_win->hide()` and `instruct_win->show()` instead?

Comment: Yes, that returns that 'virtual void Fl_Window::hide()' is inaccessible

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should work after fixing these two problems:

- You should apply the methods to objects, not to their types.

  ```
  void cb_splash_button() {
      home_win->hide();
      instruct_win->show();
  }

  void cb_instructions_button() {
      instruct_win->hide();
      //CHANGE LATER
      home_win->show();
  }
  ```
- It seems you're using FLTK, where `hide` and `show` are public members of `Fl_Window`, but `Splash_screen` and `Instructions_screen` inherit it privately, making `hide` and `show` only accessible to those classes themselves.

  Make sure that in the class definition you have something to the effect of

  ```
  class Instructions_screen : public Fl_Whatever_Window { /* ... */ }
  ```

  because without the `public` qualifier, inheritance wil be private by default.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had left out the 'public'